# How to attache multiple nodes of a node type to another node of another node type?

Tags: nodes

Currently I am making a advertisement website for restaurants. Now I am putting the restaurant basic information (name, address,etc) in a node.

What I want to do is making a menu list for the restaurant,
Say each menu item is a node (with the type of 'item') while the restaurant is another node type 'restaurant'.

In database level, the relationship between node (restaurant) and menu item node type is one-to-many.

So how can I do this?

Thanks for any help!

Cheers!

Comment: What version of Drupal?

Comment: The version of my Drupal is 7.34

Comment: Are you sure that you would like a whole node for each menu item? If the menu item were just a title, or title with price, this might be overkill, you could instead use a field with multiple values, or a field collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the [references](https://www.drupal.org/project/references) module, once you done that, you can enable the `node_reference` submodule and attach a "Node Reference" field to your "restaurant" content type.

Next, set the "item" content-type as reference for the field and the "Number of values" setting as "Unlimited".

When creating or editing a restaurant, you should now be able to link multiple menus to the node.

Comment: Thanks for posting! But I made it to add a menu item to the 'restaurant' node, however I want to add multiple menu items to one 'restaurant' node. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Isn't the solution I provided already doing what you want? I gave you a way to link unlimited node "item" to a restaurant. Once the restaurant is saved, you can generate a list of all menus from a view or using code. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Or is it that you want to create an "item" node while on a restaurant edit form? If that's what you want, there's a way but the solution I'm talking about now is based on the idea that "item" nodes already exist before coming to the "restaurant" node form.

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I want. I finally made it to attach multiple nodes to the restaurant node. Thanks for your time!

Comment: That's cool :) But before implementing that, make sure you really need a node for each menu item. As autopoietic said, if you don't need to do anything complex with those values, a well configured field  collection into the restaurant content type should be enough ;).